# jQuery increase/decrease number when checking boxes

Tags: jquery

So I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />

<div class="number">
    hello
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var increment2 = 1;
$('.checkbox').live('click', function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + increment2 + ')');
    increment2++;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/5/

It increments the number when checkbox is clicked, as can be seen in the example. The issue is to increase the number when checkbox is checked and decrease when the checkbox is unchecked. Will be very greatful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi that's your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/254/

**HTML**

```
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />
<input type=checkbox class="checkbox" />

<div class="number">
    hello
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var increment2=0; 
$('.checkbox').on('click', function() { 
    if (this.checked) {
        increment2++;                 
    } else {
        increment2--;
    }
    $('.number').html( '(' + increment2 + ')');             
})
```

Best regards!

Comment: Instead of `if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked')` you can use `if(this.checked)`. This is a much cleaner and much cheaper way.

Comment: jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.
 ".live(events, function)" should map to ".on(eventType, selector, function)"

Answer (score 5):

If you want checked checbox count you can use `:checked` selector like this:

```
$('.checkbox').live('click', function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + $(':checked').size() + ')'); 
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/9/)

And a few suggestions:

1. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to `.live()`. (from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/))
2. I suggest using `change` event instead of `click`.
3. You can select checkboxes with `:checkbox` selector. If you're using `.checkbox` class to select checkboxes it might be a better way.

Below code is a shorter version of [mgechev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106382/mgechev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728606/84042). [*](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/P3zMu/10/)

```
var increment2=0;
$('.checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + (increment2 += this.checked ? 1 : -1) + ')');             
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look here [checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
<script>
var countChecked = function() {
var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
$( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
countChecked();
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>
```